# HTML Form with POST in Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i need some help with Javascript.

Basically i have a simple form like this:

```
 <body>

<div class="wrapper">
<form class="login">
    <p class="title">Parser</p>
    <input type="Codice Identificativo" placeholder="Codice Attività" />
    <input type="Start From" placeholder="Start ID From" />
    <label class="selecttema" for="dropdown">Select Theme</label>

    <div>
    <select class="dropdown" id="dropdown" name="dropdown"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1" >Test</option>
    <option value="2" >Test1</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <button>
      <i class="spinner"></i>
      <span class="state">Go!</span>
    </button>
</form>
</p>
</div>


<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

i would like after click on the button "Go!" to send a POST Request with all parameters in JSON .

i'm assuming i can use stringify JSON into index.js but i dont know how to implement it.

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery's Ajax methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery